# Downloadable card using HTML AND CSS

Tags: html, css

How can I make a downloadable card in html and css?
I tried making a design with some writing in an enclosed div elements, it came out excellent but my question is on how to download load it to my phone.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.